# Copy order number from online shopping site

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am writing an automation script for placing an order on a shopping website. In the end, I need to copy the order number.

```
<span class="OrderLinxTx">order No.</span>
```

Identifying the order number with a class here. The problem is the same class name is shared with multiple elements such as an address, product name etc with their own classes compounded to it.

I am using find_elements_by_class_name to grab all the elements. The order number is the first element in the list every time. 
However it is not working 100% of the time, sometimes it copies the address or product name instead of the order number. I have tried time.sleep for all elements to load but with no use.

how do I copy only order number every time? I am aware that I can use XPath but I don't want to since they can change the position of the element.
Edit1: I am using python with selenium.
Edit2: [HTML of span element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2Qza.jpg)
[some more html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zV6oa.jpg). There are multiple span elements with the class name.

```html
<span tabindex="0"><br>Order#
<span class="OneLinkNoTx"> LC2784988018 </span> is complete.</span>
<p class="address OneLinkNoTx " tabindex="0">
  <span class="ttl OneLinkNoTx title" tabindex="-1">
 <a href="https://www.lastcall.com/product.jsp?itemId=prod53900168">
 Area StarsSummer Love Tote Bag</a>
</span>
  <div class="code OneLinkNoTx tabfocus itemTextCompliant" tabindex="0">Item: LCS19_V48YZ</div>
  <span class="sku-color OneLinkNoTx tabfocus" tabindex="0">Color: WHITE</span>
  <span id="qtyCI_ci1221185906" class="qty OneLinkNoTx tabfocus" qty="1" tabindex="0">Qty: 1</span>
  <span class="adornment OneLinkNoTx" tabindex="0">
<span class="finalPrice OneLinkNoTx" tabindex="0"> 
<span class="finalPrice OneLinkNoTx" tabindex="0">Price $40.00 </span>
  <p class="address OneLinkNoTx " tabindex="0">
    <span tabindex="0">Address</span> Dallas, TX 75001
    </span>
  </p>
```

Comment: Which language are you binding with selenium?can you please post more html content.

Comment: You can try this xpath : `//span[@class='OrderLinxTx'][contains(.,'order No')]`

Comment: @kunduK I am using python. The order number is generated randomly, i don't think i can use contains. Other thing is all the other elements such as address and product name also have span tags ex <span class="class1 OrderLinxTx">name</span>

Comment: If you could post more html content it will be great to answer your question

Comment: @KunduK posted html content for other elements too.

Comment: Screenshot is not going to help.You need to post html like a text.can you post your remaining html as text.

Comment: just a suggestion. you can always use the relative positioning of these elements to derive at xpath. lets says if the order number comes after the product details, you can construct an xpath accordingly.

Comment: @KunduK i have added html code. I want to grab LC2784988018 from this.

Comment: @Sureshmani I have added html which have the same class name. can you give an example based on that.

Comment: try this xpath to locate the element - //*contains(text(),'Order')]/span[@class='OneLinkNoTx']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the vale `LC2784988018` Use WebDriverWait and wait for the element `element_to_be_clickable` and use following xpath to get the text.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('Url here')
print(WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//span[contains(.,'Order')]/span[@class='OneLinkNoTx']"))).text.strip())
```

Comment: it works. Thank you. small doubt though, why use element_to_be_clickable, why not just wait for it using contains 'Order'?

Comment: It allows selenium to wait until element is clickable and explicit wait once get the element it will move on.If you give sleep it will slow down the script unnecessarily..